# Structures initialization in c

Tags: c, initialization, structure

How to initialize a structure which contains other structure definitions inside it?.

Ex:

```
struct foo{
    struct foo1{
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
    } abc;
} xyz;
```

Comment: how do you initialize a simple struct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest with modern C are designated initializers

```
struct foo xyz = { .abc = { .a = 56, } };
```

But beware that C doesn't have nested types, your `foo1` is also a global type.

Generally people prefer to separate such type declaration, first the one for `foo1` and then `foo`, from variable declarations and definitions.

Comment: I was just expecting this answer.. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

@JensGustedt shows the nice modern C way of doing it. The older school C way would be:

```
struct foo xyz = { { 1, 2, 3 } };   /* sets a, b, c to 1, 2, 3, respectively */
struct foo xyz = { { 1 } };         /* just sets the member "a" to 1
```